# Reading Log files and finding errors

Tags: string, search, kdb

I want to read all log files from a folder for current date and find lines with `"ERROR"` string.

Create a table with columns as:

```
LogName, ErrorDescription
```

`ErrorDescription` should contain entire line which has Error Entry.

For Example:

```
2023.04.17D07:05:42 : ERROR : Failed to connect
```

Please help.

Comment: This question is very vague. Are you referring to tickerplant logs or just standard text log? If you have an example input and expected output you may help produce answers for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question is vague but as example of how you might build it up:

List files in foler:

```
q)key `:myLogs
`s#`2023-04-17-process.log`2023-04-18-process.log
```

Only return `.log` files for today:

```
q){x where x like @[string[.z.d];4 7;:;"-"],"*.log"}key `:myLogs
,`2023-04-18-process.log
```

Read in the text from the files:

```
q)show each {{read0 .Q.dd[x;y]}[x] each {x where x like @[string[.z.d];4 7;:;"-"],"*"}key x}`:myLogs
"2023.04.17D07:05:42 : ERROR : Failed to connect"
"2023.04.17D07:05:42 : DEBUG : Failed to connect"
```

Split the text on `" : "`:

```
q)show each {{vs[" : "] each read0 .Q.dd[x;y]}[x] each {x where x like @[string[.z.d];4 7;:;"-"],"*"}key x}`:myLogs
"2023.04.17D07:05:42" "ERROR" "Failed to connect"
"2023.04.17D07:05:42" "DEBUG" "Failed to connect"
```

Create a table from the log fields:

```
q)raze {{{`time`level`msg!("P"$x 0;"S"$x 1;x)} each vs[" : "] each read0 .Q.dd[x;y]}[x] each {x where x like @[string[.z.d];4 7;:;"-"],"*"}key x}`:myLogs
time                          level msg
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2023.04.17D07:05:42.000000000 ERROR "2023.04.17D07:05:42" "ERROR" "Failed to connect"
2023.04.17D07:05:42.000000000 DEBUG "2023.04.17D07:05:42" "DEBUG" "Failed to connect"
```

Only return `ERROR` level logs:

```
q){select from x where level=`ERROR}raze {{{`time`level`msg!("P"$x 0;"S"$x 1;x)} each vs[" : "] each read0 .Q.dd[x;y]}[x] each {x where x like @[string[.z.d];4 7;:;"-"],"*"}key x}`:myLogs
time                          level msg
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2023.04.17D07:05:42.000000000 ERROR "2023.04.17D07:05:42" "ERROR" "Failed to connect"
```